# How to include JavaScript in a Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django

In my Django project 'pizzeria', I have created a static files folder for the app 'pizzas', so the folder structure is: pizzeria/pizzas/static/pizzas/. Inside this folder I have a JavaScript 'hack.js':

```
//hack.js
<script>   
document.getElementById("home page").innerHTML="Hacked!"
</script>
```

Now I want to include this script in my Django template (pizzeria/pizzas/templates/pizzas/base.html), however the following setup does not work (the innerHTML does not change on button click):

```
{% load static %}

<p>
<a href="{% url 'pizzas:index' %}" id="home page">Home page</a>
<a href="{% url 'pizzas:pizzas' %}">Our pizzas</a>
<button onclick="{% static 'pizzas/hack.js' %}">Hack!</button>
</p>

{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first, you are writing and HTML tag `<script>` in the onClick attribute

Comment: **Please refere this link.**

Answer (score 5):

You should remove the script tag from your js file and include it with

```
  <script src="{% static 'pizzas/hack.js' %}"></script>
```

With a hack.js file like

```
function onClick() {
   document.getElementById("home_page").innerHTML="Hacked!"
}
```

Tag ids shouldn't contain spaces, [doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)
Your button should be

```
<button onclick="onClick">Hack!</button>
```

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't work. Should `  <script src="{% static 'pizzas/hack.js' %}"></script>` be included in the template file?

Comment: yes it should be in your HTML, maybe it not working cause of your Django settings, you need to set STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS to your static files folder

Comment: STATIC_URL is set OK. I don't think I need STATICFILES_DIRS in this case, because according to the Django documentation it is used only when I want to use static files that are not tied to a particular app?

Comment: @barciewicz I edited my answer hopefully that's your issue

Comment: Django's 2.0 documentation actually says {% load static %}: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: oh true, what's you STATIC_URL setting?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: try `STATIC_URL = '/pizza/static/'` if your root folder is `pizzeria`